# How to pass JSON array to a function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. So please don't get angry if this question looks stupid to you.

This is my code.

```
var songdata = [];
$scope.getData = function(){

    $http({
        url: 'getsongdata',
        method: 'GET',

      }).then(function(resp){
         songdata = resp.data;
         console.log(songdata);
      }, function(resp){
        alert("Error Occoured.");
        console.log(resp);
      });
    };
```

Now I want to pass this songdata to as.

```
var player = new Player(songdata);
```

But it is giving me this error as:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at new Player (player.js:24)*

I can print the data on console. But I am unable to pass this as a parameter.

More code:

```
var Player = function (playlist) {
    //console.log(playlist);
    this.playlist = playlist;
    this.index = 0;

    // Display the title of the first track.
    track.innerHTML = playlist[0].title;

    // Setup the playlist display.
    playlist.forEach(function (song) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'list-song';
      div.innerHTML = song.title;
      div.onclick = function () {
        player.skipTo(playlist.indexOf(song));
      };
      list.appendChild(div);
    });
  };
```

Please help me through this.

Comment: What is `console.log(playlist);`? Can you post that too.

Comment: Yeah. It's like this: (2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
file: "F:/Music/yellow"
howl: "null"
title: "yellow"
__proto__: Object
1:
file: "F:/Music/numb"
howl: "null"
title: "numb"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: can you add `console.log(playlist);` before this line `var player = new Player(songdata);` to check if it is `undefined`.

Comment: it is printing some weird HTML code

Comment: <div id = "playlist> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Seems your http request is returning data fine but there is a calling sequence issue when you are trying to initialize - var player = new Player(songdata). Can you give a test try by intializing like this

```
.then(function(resp){
     songdata = resp.data;
     console.log(songdata);
     var player = new Player(songdata);
     //console.log(player);
```

And it is better to keep you service call at service file.

Comment: Well, I have tried that alreay but it's giving error where player is associated outside.